# How to deploy token on GETH?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether

System information

Geth version: geth the newest (updated today) version
OS & Version: Ubuntu
Commit hash : (if develop)

Expected behaviour

I expect, that machine connect Solidity with GETH, and i will deploy new Smart Token.

Actual behaviour

I was using 3 instructions from Internet, but still cant connect Solidity with ETH. Maybe there is another method to deploy smart contract without use admin.setSolc("path/to/solc")? When i type this command in geth console i have response that "setSolc is not a command".

Steps to reproduce the behaviour

Just try use admin.setSolc("path/to/your/solc") in geth console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite [quite some discussion](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3793), `admin.setSolc` has been removed from latest versions of geth. Hence you could install `solc` separately and run as a separate executable. Alternatively you can go via the very handy remix platform at remix.ethereum.org where you can compile using any version of Solidity (useful to check if old contract code still works) and you even find deploy code that you can copy-paste into your web3 console of geth to deploy a smart contract. Even better: you can test your code in a browser-based environment in a test environment without paying ether for it or running a heavy node for it.

Comment: that was helpful but im newbie, so i cant give plus. Thankyou <3

Comment: why was the ability to install a solidity compiler removed from the `geth` console?

Comment: It was regarded a very different tool and too opinionated of geth to go that route.